# What makes a graph algorithm a good candidate for concurrency?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, apache-spark, parallel

GraphX is the Apache Spark library for handling graph data. I was able to find a list of 'graph-parallel' algorithms on [these slides](http://stanford.edu/~rezab/sparkclass/slides/ankur_graphx.pdf) (see slide 23). However, I am curious what characteristics of these algorithms make them parallelizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two words: associative and commutative

In other words, the operations that the algorithm does need to be independent of how you order or group your data...this minimizes the need for cross-talk in the algorithm and leads to more efficiency.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these terms?

Comment: @sheldonkreger the operations that the algorithm does need to be independent of how you order or group your data...this minimizes the need for cross-talk in the algorithm and leads to more efficiency.